# Changes in UI mess with design of the "lab bench"

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I don't know since when this appears the way it does, but it must have been rather recently. Originally the box on which the lab equipment sits was stretching in the green background ([compare here, it's old, I know](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENL4X.jpg)). Now there is a space which makes it look very weird:

[image: weird spacing]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

thanks for reporting. This is indeed because of black top bar becoming taller. Fix is waiting in repo for next build, so you should be able to see it in next couple hours.